# Headless chrome + ignore-certificate-errors

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver

I need to get headless chrome to ignore certificate errors. The option is ignored when running in headless mode, and the driver returns empty html body tags when navigating to an https resource.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body></body></html>
```

This is how I am configuring my chrome driver.

```
 ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
 chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1200","--ignore-certificate-errors");

 DesiredCapabilities cap=DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

 cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
 cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
 cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);
 chromeHeadlessDriver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

[This thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/headless-dev/eiudRsYdc3A/BLuLMTX_BgAJ) confirms that `--ignore-certificate-errors` is ignored in headless mode.

They mention about [devtool protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Security/).

Is it something I can invoke from java? Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: support for "acceptInsecureCerts" will be added to chromedriver 
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=721739

Comment: The DevTool API can be called with Selenium with this endpoint: `/session/:sessionId/chromium/send_command_and_get_result`. This  command is specific to the Chrome driver and is not yet implemented in the client. You could implement it yourself with a few lines of code by overriding the command executor.

Answer (score 9):

There is an excellent article on [medium.com by sahajamit](https://medium.com/@sahajamit/selenium-chrome-dev-tools-makes-a-perfect-browser-automation-recipe-c35c7f6a2360)

and i have tested the below code, it works perfectly fine with self-signed certificate https://badssl.com/

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
    options.addArguments("--headless", "--window-size=1920,1200","--ignore-certificate-errors");

    DesiredCapabilities crcapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    crcapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    crcapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    crcapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);

    System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_LOG_PROPERTY, "C:\\temp\\chrome\\chromedriver.log");
    System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY, "C:\\temp\\chrome\\chromedriver.exe");

    ChromeDriverService service = null;
    try {
        service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
                .usingAnyFreePort()
                .withVerbose(true)
                .build();
        service.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(),crcapabilities);

    driver.get("https://self-signed.badssl.com/");
    System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
    driver.quit();
```

software/framework versions

- Google Chrome Version 64.0.3282.186
- Google Chrome Driver Version 64.0.3282.186
- Selenium version 3.11.0

Comment: Yeah, it was fixed in chrome 65, already using it. This is an old post. All the details are in the link for the chromium issue

Comment: i just added this for others reference :)

Comment: @Amilakumura You made my day ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4):

This works for me on ChromeDriver 80.

```
ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
option.AddArgument("--headless");
option.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;
driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
```

Answer (score 3):

@amila-kumara is working but, usage of `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()` gives warning to use **ChromeOptions**. Please see the updated answer.

Set the chrome option values

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Config.NDAC_WEBDRIVER_PATH);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1200");
options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
options.setHeadless(true);
```

Start the service

```
ChromeDriverService service = null;
try {
    service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
            .usingAnyFreePort()
            .withVerbose(true)
            .build();
    service.start();
    remoteWebdriverUrl = service.getUrl();
    System.out.println("Starting the url " + remoteWebdriverUrl);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Note:** I was facing the issue while closing the driver(with RemoteWebDriver), chromedriver.exe process won't close even when you use **driver.quit()**. To fix the issue use **ChromeDriver instead of RemoteWebDriver**

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
```

To properly close the driver, use

```
driver.close();
driver.quit();
```

Comment: options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true); saved my life!!! Thanks.