# Protractor tests not working in chrome headless mode

Tags: google-chrome, protractor, headless

```
element(by.id('username')).sendKeys('deepu');
```

this throws the following error in headless mode,

**Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="username"])**

this is running fine in normal mode.

**My package.json**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "jasmine": "2.4.1",
    "typescript": "^2.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.51",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.0",
    "chromedriver": "^2.34.1",
    "protractor": "^5.2.2",
    "protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter": "0.0.7",
    "selenium-server-standalone-jar": "^3.8.1",
    "ts-node": "^3.0.2"
  }
```

**Chrome version**
63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Thanks in advance,
Deepu.

**UPDATE**

The actual problem was in ignoring certificate errors in the headless Chrome.

I was able to run the tests fine, bypassing the untrusted certificate warning from browser, with Protractor and Firefox Quantum(57.0.4, 64-bit) headless, but had to run a standalone selenium, couldn't find anything similar to chromedriver

```
  framework: 'jasmine',
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox',
    acceptInsecureCerts: true,
    'moz:firefoxOptions': {
       args: [ "--headless" ]
     }
  },
  specs: [ './specs/login.spec.js' ],
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
```

Comment: Did you try add a long sleep before sendKeys()?  But from my understanding headless mode should load page fast then normal mode, anyway you can give a try sleep.

Comment: That was not the poblem, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510973/headless-chrome-ignore-certificate-errors
This is my actual issue.

Comment: thanks for looking into this @yong

Comment: The actual problem was in ignoring certificate errors in the headless Chrome. Certain security related options like '--ignore-certificate-errors'are silently ignored in headless mode. See more details here,

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=721739

Best Regards,
Deepu.

Comment: ```
        acceptInsecureCerts: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true,
```

Comment: "acceptInsecureCerts: true" was the answer in my case as well, not sure if it's worth updating the answer for this to reflect that since failure to find an element on the page is such a red herring for these tests.