# C# with Selenium xunit testing Bypass SSL Error "Your connection is not private"

Tags: c#, testing, xunit

I am using xunit test framework with C# to automate testing of a web app. But when I run the tests the automatically opened browser can not proceed to the website because of ssl error and is **displaying "Your connection is not private" message and the test fails** due to this. **DesiredCapabilities** class, which was a solution to the problem is deprecated. What is the solution?

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510973/headless-chrome-ignore-certificate-errors/51592301)

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1200","--ignore-certificate-errors");
```

Comment: So, in other words, your question is a duplicate of that one?